# Using instance name in str() function of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a class about points in cartesian system (each point instance having abscissa and ordinate) and each instance has its name, for example we have point 'A' (coordinates (2,3)) and 'B'(coordinates(1,2)). 
In the **str**()  function i need  to use the name of the instance to have a nice output.
For example i need the program to print out ( Abscissa of A is 2) when using the print command (print(A)) 
And displaying ( Abscissa of B is 1) when (print(B)) is written in main script. 
The main problem is to have the name of instance displayed. 
Is there a function that returns the name of instance of a certain class?

I tried using  self.namehex(id(self)) in the init()  function and then use self.name() but it didn't do the trick

Comment: Please add the code of your `Point` class to your question.

Comment: If you are referring to something like `a = Point(3, 5)`, `a` is not part of the object itself; it's an external reference *to* an object. The object itself doesn't know anything about what names refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chepner commented, objects don't know the names they're assigned.

If you want your Point class to know its instance name, add it as an argument to `__init__()`.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'abcissa of %s is ...' % self.name

a = Point('a', 50, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the **repr** or **str** method. **repr** is used when you use print on the object and **str** when you use str(object).

```
class SomeClass:

def __init__(self, name, x, y):
    self.name = name
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __repr__(self):
    return f'abscissa of name: {self.name}  is...'

def __str__(self):
    return f'abscissa of name: {self.name}  is...'
```

OUTPUT:

a = SomeClass('name', 4, 6)
b = SomeClass('name2', 9, 8)

a
abscissa of name: name  is... 
b
abscissa of name: name2  is...
str(a)
'abscissa of name: name  is...'
str(b)
'abscissa of name: name2  is...'